# Get device Information using mern

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I want to make a system where I have some facilities like: (Reactjs nodejs)

1. we can logout user from their device (it would be good if we can remove also localstorage data)
2. we can watch user is online or offline
3. we can get users device information like(mac adress) for unique identify

Hi, I want to make a system where I have some facilities like: (Reactjs nodejs)

1. we can logout user from their device (it would be good if we can remove also localstorage data)
2. we can watch user is online or offline .
3. we can get users device information like(mac adress) for unique identify

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.